# The ideal way to write permutation function in OCaml

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, ocaml, permutation

Given a list, and output a list of all its permutations.

Here is my thinking:

Recursively, a permutation of `hd::tl` is to distribute `hd` into each list of the permutations of `tl`. By distributing `hd`, I mean inserting `hd` into every possible slot among the list.

For example, distributing `1` into `[2;3]` generates `[[1;2;3];[2;1;3];[2;3;1]]`.

So here is the code

```
let distribute c l =
  let rec insert acc1 acc2 = function
    | [] -> acc2
    | hd::tl ->
      insert (hd::acc1) ((List.rev_append acc1 (hd::c::tl)) :: acc2) tl
  in 
  insert [] [c::l] l

let rec permutation = function
  | [] -> [[]]
  | hd::tl -> 
    List.fold_left (fun acc x -> List.rev_append (distribute hd x) acc) [] (permutation tl)
```

---

I guess the above code is correct.

**My question** is: is there any better way (in terms of simplicity, performance, space efficiency, etc) to write permutations in OCaml?

Comment: Wouldn't all permutations of [1;2;3] be [1;2;3],[1;3;2],[2;1;3],[2;3;1],[3;1;2],[3;2;1] ?

Comment: @aneccodeal yes. please note the example I gave is just for `distribute`, not for `permutation`

Comment: If you care about performance you could code the result directly for small lists near the bottom of the recursion. If you want permutations of medium sized lists, you might recode the result as a stream rather than a list. (You can't realistically get all the permutations of list longer than 13 or 14.)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield are you talking about lazy list? If so, i think it is a good point. could you please build an answer out of it?

Comment: Yes, lazy list. It's a challenge to generate permutations lazily, I think. I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I wrote a stream-based implementation along the lines I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that generates a stream (i.e., a lazy list) of permutations. This avoids having to hold the entire list in memory at once. It could let you work with longer lists if you only need a limited number of permutations.

To keep things simpler I'm using Jane Street Core as my base library.

```
open Core.Std

let permutations lst =
    let lstar = Array.of_list lst in
    let len = Array.length lstar in
    let ks = List.range 1 (len + 1) in
    let indices = Int.Set.of_list (List.range 0 len) in
    let choose k (v, indices, res) =
        let ix = Option.value_exn (Int.Set.find_index indices (v mod k)) in
        (v / k, Int.Set.remove indices ix, lstar.(ix) :: res)
    in
    let perm i =
        let (v, _, res) =
            List.fold_right ks ~f: choose ~init: (i, indices, [])
        in
        if v > 0 then None else Some res
    in
    Stream.from perm
```

Here's a session with this implementation:

```
# let s = permutations ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'];;
val s : char list Stream.t = <abstr>
# Stream.npeek 100 s;;
- : char list list =
[[d; c; b; a]; [d; c; a; b]; [d; b; a; c]; [c; b; a; d]; [d; b; c; a];
 [d; a; c; b]; [d; a; b; c]; [c; a; b; d]; [c; b; d; a]; [c; a; d; b];
 [b; a; d; c]; [b; a; c; d]; [c; d; b; a]; [c; d; a; b]; [b; d; a; c];
 [b; c; a; d]; [b; d; c; a]; [a; d; c; b]; [a; d; b; c]; [a; c; b; d];
 [b; c; d; a]; [a; c; d; b]; [a; b; d; c]; [a; b; c; d]]
# let s = permutations (List.range 0 10);;
val s : int list Stream.t = <abstr>
# Stream.iter ignore s;;
- : unit = ()
# Stream.count s;;
- : int = 3628800
# fact 10;;
- : int = 3628800
```

The key idea is that you can number permutations in a way that makes it easy to extract the permutation itself from its index. The intuition is similar to the way you can number the decimal representations of integers. To extract the decimal representation of a 4-digit number from its index you can do something like this:

```
let digits i =
    let ks = [10;10;10;10] in
    let extract k (v, result) = (v / k, v mod k :: result) in
    let (_, res) = List.fold_right ks ~f: extract ~init: (i, []) in
    res
```

Note that this works using 10 as the divisor every time. To extract a permutation, you do something very similar except you use n, n - 1, n - 2, ..., 1 as your divisors.

Answer (score 5):

Other approaches include a) for each element, prepend it to each of the permutations of the list excluding the element, or b) generate permutations from each of the n! indices. See the [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#OCaml) examples.  I suspect these have similar space complexities.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is basically an "insertion-based" approach -- where you go through the input list in order and then "insert" each subsequent input element into the partial results in every possible way.

Another way you can do it is a "selection-based" approach -- where you build up each subsequent element of the result list by "selecting" every possibility from the unused values. Formally, a permutation has a first element from any element of the input list, and the part of the permutation after the first element comes from any permutation of the "rest" of the input list. This generates all permutations.

The tricky part is how to get the "rest of the list". The simplest way is to write a "delete" function which takes a value and a list and returns a copy of the list without the first element equal to the given element. However, this runs into issues for languages that don't have equality for all types, or where you want to distinguish distinct but equal elements. A more correct way is to generate both the element and "rest of list" together as you iterate the list.